# Adding React into large PHP project (ZF3)

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, typescript, zend-framework3

Hello fellow developers,

I have a lack of knowledge about NodeJS, React and JS technologies but I have a need to implement basic React functions in a large PHP project.

**The project:**

- uses Zend Framework 3 (MVC, project divided into modules etc.)
- PHP packages are managed by composer (*composer.json*)
- runs on IBM I server
- recently added Typescript
- Javascript packages managed by npm

I have little knowledge about npm and what is required for some packages to work.

**What I want to achieve:**

- add React in order to generate views with JS
- add it through *package.json*
- import it to my Typescript file

**What I've tried:**

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "...",
  "homepage": "...",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.31",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.14",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "..."
  }
}
```

**index.ts**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

I installed packages on the server but got the following error during TS compilation:

```
module/Dashboard/asset/dashboard/js/index.ts:12:19 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'react'.

12 import React from 'react';
                     ~~~~~~~
module/Dashboard/asset/dashboard/js/index.ts:13:22 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'react-dom'.

13 import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

I've tried importing it *require* but it's not working without NodeJS. Is *require* library worth to use instead of import?

What did I do wrong in installing the React this way and what should I do? Are there additional requirements that I didn't met? The React is working when I import it in HTML as described [HERE](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html).

Additional questions:

- Is mixing Zend Framework 3 / PHP project with JS libraries a good idea?
- How to do it properly?

Thank you in advance

**EDIT:**
My team decided to think whether we should include this functionality as a part of Zend Framework 3 module or create a Front end application which will ask the ZF3 module through API. We will probably choose the 2nd option.
I would be pleased if someone would give me a constructive comment on that matter. Is this architectural approach is a good way to go?

Comment: This question is probably better asked on the Software Engineering community site. At a glance it sounds like the right solution is to have a separate React frontend that comsumes a PHP backend API.

Answer (score -1):

In order to conquer your

> Cannot find module 'react'.

problem you should install node module 'react' in your project directory  with running

> npm install react

in terminal.

Use require In order to import 'react' modules rather than import

Should the react front-end be ran by a separate instance of service and communicate with PHP by API or maybe are you running PHP code from node or what?

Comment: React was already installed in node_modules folder by adding it to **package.json** and running **npm install**. Require was not working in this case as the command was not found. Probably because it's NodeJS command.  

My team decided to think whether we should include this functionality as a part of Zend Framework 3 module or create a Front end application which will ask the ZF3 module through API. We will probably choose the 2nd option.

Comment: @AleksanderSil IMHO, second approach is the right way to go. React frontend that consumes API